# Calculate Acos in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I am trying to calculate acos in ArcMap (shp) using Python. Here is the code:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc_Arcs, "Angle", math.acos(0.88), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

If I set the value i.e. 0.88 I am getting the output. However, I want to set the formula to calculate angle for all records in the shp.

I've tried to set the formula:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc_Arcs, "Angle", math.acos('!X!/!Radius!'), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

and I've got the error "TypeError: a float is required"

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using the python math.acos external to the field calculator to calculate the acos. So Python sees this as a string rather than a float (hence the error).

Try instead to place the full expression in quotation marks.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc_Arcs, "Angle", "math.acos(!X!/!Radius!)", "PYTHON_9.3"
```